# php login redirects and logs into https (like gmail, etc)

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, gmail, autologin

I was hoping to create a php script that allows me to provide a person a link and give them specific login credentials. When the user goes to the page and logins I would then like it to redirect them to an https site like gmail and have it auto login with my creditials. It's kind of a round about way to allow someone to access my email without them knowing my password. I know this is probably a very dumb way of doing this but I'm new with php and am not sure how exactly I would accomplish this task or if its even php for that matter, haha.

This is the code I have to log in:

HTML:

```
<h1>Login</h1> 

<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <p><label for="txtUsername">Username:</label> 
    <br /><input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" /></p>

    <p><label for="txtpassword">Password:</label> 
    <br /><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" /></p> 

    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></p> 

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

// Define your username and password 
$username = "admin"; 
$password = "password"; 

if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 

?> 


<?php 

} 
else { 

?>
```

website html

```
<?php 

} 

?>
```

I apologize for the horrible style and butchering the code but this is literally the first thing i've written in php. Also I've seen a good amount of posts related to what i'm asking but doesn't fully answer it. thanks!

Comment: You want a proxy system. Otherwise you're in for a long ugly literal metric rump-load of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't do this!

you're adding insecurity to your account for no reason. Google already has this feature under `settings` > `Accounts and Import` > `Grant access to your account`

If you were to set up a page for someone to go to to log in as you, anyone who stumbled across your page could then have full access to your account. Granting access instead would just allow another user limited privileges to your account, and you'd always be able to prevent them from accessing it in the future.

Comment: Whoops, much easier. Thank you for the help.